# Does CMake add_compile_options affect linker options when appropriate?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

Some compiler options may actually require extra *link* options in order to actually be effective. For instance, to enable [GCC's Link Time Optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization#Using_LTO), the `-flto` option must be passed both in the compilation command *and* the link command.

There's a spiffy [builtin `cmake` command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_compile_options.html) for adding compile options but, as far as I know, no corresponding command for link options. Even if there were, needing to specify them explicitly when they're implied by the compile options I'm using would be pretty annoying.

So does `add_compile_options(-flto)` add `-flto` to the *link* command? If not, do I need to `set(LINK_FLAGS ....` directly?

Answer (score 6):

`add_compile_options` and `target_compile_options` will *not* get passed to the linker.

Use [`add_link_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_link_options.html) instead for this purpose.

On older CMake versions (older than 3.13), you can (ab)use [`target_link_libraries` for this purpose](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html):

> Item names starting with -, but not -l or -framework, are treated as
> linker flags.

Comment: Hm. I'd really prefer (for now) to set the option globally within my project, and you're right that using `target_link_libraries` here seems like an abuse, at least semantically. Good solution, though.

Comment: ....you haven't by any chance managed to get `-flto` working with CMake in any of your projects, have you?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in cmake versions 3.13 onwards using [add_link_options()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/add_link_options.html).